# aws/azure fail to run a build for react app

Tags: node.js, reactjs, amazon-web-services, azure, npm

SOLVED:

The problem was that I've saved my 10400 objects of json data as .js array and it made the build to take to long (I just didnt know how to handle json), now it .json and everything works fine.

---

I made a react app and it works fine on the localhost (and also on ngrok) but when I'm trying to deploy the app to Azure(or AWS) the build fails.

On my computer I tried `npm run build` and it succeded but took about 10 min(m1 macbbok pro).

Maybe there a way to run the build on my computer and push that build to AWS?
(so AWS wont have to waste time on build and then fail)

package.json

```
    {
  "name": "az-demo",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.14.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^11.2.7",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^12.8.3",
    "qrcode": "^1.4.4",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-qrcodes": "^1.0.7",
    "react-scripts": "4.0.3",
    "react-table": "^7.7.0",
    "web-vitals": "^1.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

aws logs:

```
                                     # Starting phase: preBuild
                                 # Executing command: npm ci
2021-10-08T21:24:48.088Z [INFO]: > core-js-pure@3.18.2 postinstall /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/core-js-pure
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2021-10-08T21:24:48.130Z [INFO]: [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
                                 [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js:[0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://patreon.com/zloirock [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://paypal.me/zloirock [0m
                                 [96m>[94m bitcoin: bc1qlea7544qtsmj2rayg0lthvza9fau63ux0fstcz [0m
                                 [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
2021-10-08T21:24:48.242Z [INFO]: > core-js@2.6.12 postinstall /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/babel-runtime/node_modules/core-js
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2021-10-08T21:24:48.282Z [INFO]: [96mThank you for using core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock/core-js [96m) for polyfilling JavaScript standard library![0m
                                 [96mThe project needs your help! Please consider supporting of core-js on Open Collective or Patreon: [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://opencollective.com/core-js [0m
                                 [96m>[94m https://www.patreon.com/zloirock [0m
                                 [96mAlso, the author of core-js ([94m https://github.com/zloirock [96m) is looking for a good job -)[0m
2021-10-08T21:24:48.316Z [INFO]: > ejs@2.7.4 postinstall /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/ejs
                                 > node ./postinstall.js
2021-10-08T21:24:48.352Z [INFO]: Thank you for installing [35mEJS[0m: built with the [32mJake[0m JavaScript build tool ([32mhttps://jakejs.com/[0m)
2021-10-08T21:24:48.516Z [INFO]: > fsevents@1.2.13 install /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/webpack-dev-server/node_modules/fsevents
                                 > node install.js
2021-10-08T21:24:48.554Z [INFO]: 
2021-10-08T21:24:48.555Z [INFO]: Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
2021-10-08T21:24:48.581Z [INFO]: > fsevents@1.2.13 install /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/watchpack-chokidar2/node_modules/fsevents
                                 > node install.js
2021-10-08T21:24:48.617Z [INFO]: 
2021-10-08T21:24:48.617Z [INFO]: Skipping 'fsevents' build as platform linux is not supported
2021-10-08T21:24:48.768Z [INFO]: > core-js@3.18.2 postinstall /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/core-js
                                 > node -e "try{require('./postinstall')}catch(e){}"
2021-10-08T21:24:49.236Z [INFO]: added 1990 packages in 10.711s
2021-10-08T21:24:49.248Z [INFO]: # Completed phase: preBuild
                                 # Starting phase: build
2021-10-08T21:24:49.249Z [INFO]: # Executing command: npm run build
2021-10-08T21:24:49.409Z [INFO]: > az-demo@0.1.0 build /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS
                                 > react-scripts build
2021-10-08T21:24:50.514Z [INFO]: Creating an optimized production build...
2021-10-08T21:25:40.146Z [INFO]: <--- Last few GCs --->
                                 [1265:0x4bdfeb0]    49291 ms: Scavenge 1974.9 (1996.2) -> 1974.0 (2019.0) MB, 11.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.372, current mu = 0.462) allocation failure
                                 [1265:0x4bdfeb0]    49328 ms: Scavenge 1990.4 (2019.0) -> 1989.6 (2020.2) MB, 14.0 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.372, current mu = 0.462) allocation failure
                                 [1265:0x4bdfeb0]    49347 ms: Scavenge 1991.3 (2020.2) -> 1989.5 (2033.0) MB, 16.7 / 0.0 ms  (average mu = 0.372, current mu = 0.462) allocation failure
                                 <--- JS stacktrace --->
                                 ==== JS stack trace =========================================
                                 0: ExitFrame [pc: 0x140a7f9]
                                 Security context: 0x11c972a408d1 <JSObject>
                                 1: /* anonymous */(aka /* anonymous */) [0x20231a5c2891] [/codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/webpack-sources/lib/ReplaceSource.js:~122] [pc=0x20e8ba2fedd9](this=0x38c384a804b1 <undefined>,0x3e520dbd80f9 <String[7]: "type":>,0x3936c6875699 <Object map = 0x23df49a78f9>)
                                 2: walk(aka SourceNode_walk) [0x12a2576ee5f1] [/codebuild/output/sr...
2021-10-08T21:25:40.147Z [WARNING]: FATAL ERROR: Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory
2021-10-08T21:25:40.219Z [WARNING]: 1: 0xa18150 node::Abort() [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.219Z [WARNING]: 2: 0xa1855c node::OnFatalError(char const*, char const*) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.220Z [WARNING]: 3: 0xb9705e v8::Utils::ReportOOMFailure(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.221Z [WARNING]: 4: 0xb973d9 v8::internal::V8::FatalProcessOutOfMemory(v8::internal::Isolate*, char const*, bool) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.221Z [WARNING]: 5: 0xd54655  [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.222Z [WARNING]: 6: 0xd54ce6 v8::internal::Heap::RecomputeLimits(v8::internal::GarbageCollector) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.222Z [WARNING]: 7: 0xd615a5 v8::internal::Heap::PerformGarbageCollection(v8::internal::GarbageCollector, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.223Z [WARNING]: 8: 0xd62455 v8::internal::Heap::CollectGarbage(v8::internal::AllocationSpace, v8::internal::GarbageCollectionReason, v8::GCCallbackFlags) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.223Z [WARNING]: 9: 0xd63aff v8::internal::Heap::HandleGCRequest() [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.224Z [WARNING]: 10: 0xd12565 v8::internal::StackGuard::HandleInterrupts() [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.224Z [WARNING]: 11: 0x106dba6 v8::internal::Runtime_StackGuard(int, unsigned long*, v8::internal::Isolate*) [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:40.225Z [WARNING]: 12: 0x140a7f9  [/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node]
2021-10-08T21:25:57.789Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-10-08T21:25:57.790Z [WARNING]: ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
                                    npm ERR! errno 1
2021-10-08T21:25:57.791Z [WARNING]: npm
2021-10-08T21:25:57.791Z [WARNING]: ERR! az-demo@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                    npm ERR! Exit status 1
                                    npm ERR!
                                    npm ERR! Failed at the az-demo@0.1.0 build script.
                                    npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
2021-10-08T21:25:57.814Z [WARNING]: 
2021-10-08T21:25:57.815Z [WARNING]: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
                                    npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2021-10-08T21_25_57_791Z-debug.log
2021-10-08T21:25:57.815Z [HELP]: Outputting the npm debug log
                                 0 info it worked if it ends with ok
                                 1 verbose cli [
                                 1 verbose cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node',
                                 1 verbose cli   '/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/npm',
                                 1 verbose cli   'run',
                                 1 verbose cli   'build'
                                 1 verbose cli ]
                                 2 info using npm@6.14.11
                                 3 info using node@v12.21.0
                                 4 verbose run-script [ 'prebuild', 'build', 'postbuild' ]
                                 5 info lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~prebuild: az-demo@0.1.0
                                 6 info lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: az-demo@0.1.0
                                 7 verbose lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: unsafe-perm in lifecycle true
                                 8 verbose lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: PATH: /root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/node-gyp-bin:/codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS/node_modules/.bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6/bin:/usr/local/rvm/gems/ruby-2.4.6@global/bin:/usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-2.4.6/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/root/.yarn/bin:/root/.config/yarn/global/node_modules/.bin:/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin:/root/.local/bin:/root/.local/bin:/usr/local/rvm/bin:/usr/local/sbin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/sbin:/usr/bin:/sbin:/bin:/root/.dotnet/tools
                                 9 verbose lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: CWD: /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS
                                 10 silly lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: Args: [ '-c', 'react-scripts build' ]
                                 11 silly lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: Returned: code: 1  signal: null
                                 12 info lifecycle az-demo@0.1.0~build: Failed to exec build script
                                 13 verbose stack Error: az-demo@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                 13 verbose stack Exit status 1
                                 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/index.js:332:16)
                                 13 verbose stack     at EventEmitter.emit (events.js:314:20)
                                 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/lib/node_modules/npm/node_modules/npm-lifecycle/lib/spawn.js:55:14)
                                 13 verbose stack     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:314:20)
                                 13 verbose stack     at maybeClose (internal/child_process.js:1022:16)
                                 13 verbose stack     at Process.ChildProcess._handle.onexit (internal/child_process.js:287:5)
                                 14 verbose pkgid az-demo@0.1.0
                                 15 verbose cwd /codebuild/output/src164638141/src/TAU-ICS
                                 16 verbose Linux 4.14.243-185.433.amzn2.x86_64
                                 17 verbose argv "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/node" "/root/.nvm/versions/node/v12.21.0/bin/npm" "run" "build"
                                 18 verbose node v12.21.0
                                 19 verbose npm  v6.14.11
                                 20 error code ELIFECYCLE
                                 21 error errno 1
                                 22 error az-demo@0.1.0 build: `react-scripts build`
                                 22 error Exit status 1
                                 23 error Failed at the az-demo@0.1.0 build script.
                                 23 error This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.
                                 24 verbose exit [ 1, true ]
2021-10-08T21:25:57.818Z [ERROR]: !!! Build failed
2021-10-08T21:25:57.818Z [ERROR]: !!! Non-Zero Exit Code detected
2021-10-08T21:25:57.818Z [INFO]: # Starting environment caching...
2021-10-08T21:25:57.819Z [INFO]: # Environment caching completed
Terminating logging...
```

Answer (score 0):

`Ineffective mark-compacts near heap limit Allocation failed - JavaScript heap out of memory`

Change your codebuild compute specs to maybe same as your m1. After that you can optimize and see how much memory and cpu is used.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-compute-types.html

For azure you could do the same